# Переопределение элемента статического свойства - массива, но не всего массива

Tags: php, ооп

Вопрос такой: допустим, есть некий класс, содержащий статическое свойство - массив:

```
class BaseClass {
    public static $definition = array(
        'id' => array(type => 'int', 'required' => true),
        'field1' => array(type => 'string', 'required' => true),
        'field2' => array(type => 'bool', 'required' => true),
        // и еще 100500 элементов
    );
}
```

Я наследую этот класс, и хочу переопределить массив, НО изменить содержимое всего лишь одного элемента этого массива. Т.е., вместо того, чтобы тащить все 100500 элементов в дочерний класс ради одного изменения

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    public static $definition = array(
        'id' => array(type => 'int', 'required' => true),
        'field1' => array(type => 'string', 'required' => false), // единственное изменение
        'field2' => array(type => 'bool', 'required' => true),
        // и еще 100500 элементов без изменений
    );
}
```

душа просит чего-то вроде этого

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    // да да, так нельзя, я знаю :)
    public static $definition['field1']['required'] = true;
}
```

Есть ли какая-то подобная возможность?

Заранее спасибо.

P.S. и да, к этому свойству возможно обращение в статическом контексте, поэтому просто сделать это в конструкторе наследуемого класса - недостаточно.

P.P.S. ну и еще, для понимания: такова уж архитектура движка, живем с тем, что есть. другими словами, вопрос про то, "что сделать в этой ситуации", а не про то, "как в нее не попадать" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Статические свойства принадлежат классу, а не объектам, поэтому изменять их по прихоти потомка...
Лучше скопировать в приватное свойство и там изменять что нужно.
Но, если изменение - не проблема (что делать крайне не рекомендуется из-за неочевидности), то изменить предка можно через `parent::$definition['field1']['required'] = true;`, но это из метода.
Как безумный вариант-костыль: после определения класса вызвать метод, изменяющий предка:

```
class _Parent{
  public static $def = [
    'someone' => true
  ];
}

class Target extends _Parent{
  static function change(){
    parent::$def['someone'] = false;
  }

  static function get(){
    return Target::$def['someone'];
  }
}
Target::change();
```

Comment: ха, кстати норм костыль, как-то упустил... безумный - да, но какая архитектура - такие и костыли -))

Comment: только не понял, к чему в примере get() ?

Comment: @AlexandrX, да, язык странный. Но это классно, не всё же безопасно кодить на шарпе :) `get` просто для примера, забыл вырезать после проверки.